# How to carry row id on javascript function?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax

I'm a beginner in this area, I have made my coding based on other example. 
I want to make dynamic dropdown based on two dropdown, which is when the 1st selected and the 2nd will be filtered based on the 1st dropdown.
But the problem is when multiple row, the code is not function because it doesn't carry the row id, I don't know how carry the row id on that function

Below are the code that I've made

financialDataList.jsp

```html
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">

function addRowToTable()
{
    var tbl = document.getElementById('data');
    var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
    var iteration = lastRow-1;                
    var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);
    row.vAlign = "top";

    var cnt = iteration+1

    //cell 1                
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var elem1 = document.createElement('select');
    elem1.setAttribute("id","typeCode"+iteration);
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value='';
    option.textContent='-Select-';
    elem1.name = 'typeCod'; 
    //alert("[ "+this.value+" , "+elem1+" , "+option+" , "+elem1.value+" ]");
    elem1.setAttribute("onchange","showAcct(this.value, 'acctCode"+iteration+"')"); 
    elem1.appendChild(option);
    cell1.appendChild(elem1); 

    // generate list of typeCod option value for select 
    var finTypeLOV = document.forms[0].finTypeLOV.value; 
    var tFinTypeLOV = finTypeLOV.split("|");

    for (i = 0; i < tFinTypeLOV.length; i++){
        if (tFinTypeLOV[i] != '') {
            var tFinTypeValue = tFinTypeLOV[i].split("=");
            appendOptionLast("typeCode"+iteration, tFinTypeValue[0], tFinTypeValue[1]);
        }
    } 

    //cell 2                                
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var elem2 = document.createElement('select');
    elem2.setAttribute("id","acctCode"+iteration); 
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value=''; 
    option.textContent='-Select-';
    elem2.name = 'acctCod'; 
    elem2.appendChild(option);
    cell2.appendChild(elem2);
}

var xmlHttp  
function showAcct(typeCod,id){ 
    xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
    if (xmlHttp==null)
    {
        alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request")
        return
    }
    var url="financialDataDropdown.jsp";
    url +="?typeCod=" +typeCod+ "&id=" +id; 
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = acctChange;
    xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function acctChange(){ 
    frm = document.forms['form1']; 
    var tbl = document.getElementById('data'); 
    var lastRow = tbl.rows.length; 
    var iteration = lastRow-2; 
    if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete"){ 
        if(frm.typeCod.size != 0 || frm.acctCod.id != "acctCode"){ 
            var id2 = "acctCode"+iteration; //nilainyer acctCode2
            document.getElementById(id2).innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("acctCode").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText; 
        }
    }   
}

function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
    var xmlHttp=null;
    try
    {
        // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
        xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        //Internet Explorer
        try
        {
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    }
    return xmlHttp;
}
</script>
<!--.........some code not show here..........-->
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select id="typeCode" name='typeCod' onchange="showAcct(this.value, 'acctCode')">  
            <%
                opt = fin.optionRefFinType(false, typeCod, typeCod);
                for (int i = 0; i < opt.size(); i++) {
            %>
            <%=opt.elementAt(i)%>
            <% }%>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td> 
            <select id='acctCode' name='acctCod' >  
                <option value='-1'>-Select-</option>  
            </select>  
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Above is the javascript that I've made, I use function addRowToTable() to add multiple row with the same function I want on the default row.

I call `showAcct()` function `onchange` at the 1st dropdown.

Comment: Thank you @Passerby because make a correction by editing my question.